# View raw data in power bi

Tags: azure, powerbi, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

I have stream analytics in azure that sends data to power bi. The data is a complex JSON and I am trying to write a proper query for stream analytics to get the data I need.

I wrote some query, but it returns a record and I cannot figure out what fields are inside the record. In power bi if I drag the field, it just says Record. I assume this is probably a list of JSON records. Is there any way to see the record as JSON or raw text in Power BI (or anywhere else)? I want to see the output of stream analytics, so I could improve my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of outputting to Power BI, you could output to blob storage, where you'll be able to see the raw data.

Alternatively, you could use the Query tab in the old Azure portal to "test" your Stream Analytics query on a sample input file. The testing feature will show you the schema of your output.

Comment: This surely will work, but this is weird. If I have data in Power BI, why can't I view it? I do not have any spare blob storage, it is cumbersome for me to create it (I haven't done this yet, I'm new to Azure). Old Azure portal with "test" worked for me, but I could not get a test sample - whatever date I set it always says that there is no data. I actually had to sniff sending server to get a schema sample.